# Why have my Gnucash reports stopped working

Tags: gnucash

For some reason Gnucash Reports no longer work on my Ubuntu 20.04 Flatpack installation. They were working last week. After setting report parameters I get a blank screen. No Error message. After consulting Gnu cash support I have found that if I export the "blank screen" to an .html file I can open the report with firefox. I think it's something to do with Flatpack,an upgrade to Firefox, a ubuntu update,and new file paths but I am not technically proficient enough to find and correct them

Comment: What does "stopped working" mean? Do you get an error message? If so, please [edit] your question to include it

Answer (score 8):

This happened to me today, and appears to be an issue with flatpak updates.

Workaround for me was to launch from the terminal:

```
WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1 flatpak run org.gnucash.GnuCash
```

See further discussion here:

- https://bugs.gnucash.org/show_bug.cgi?id=798486
- https://bugs.gnucash.org/show_bug.cgi?id=798537

Edited to add: Better solution from the bug reports is to run `flatpak update` first. For me, this updated Nvidia drivers and solves the issue without needing to run through terminal.

Comment: For those without flatpack it is basically the same thing:
WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1 gnucash

Comment: I had to update my Nvidia driver for an unrelated incident this morning, dropping from 515 to 510 (Ubuntu 22.04). Forgot I did that. Shocked to find gnucash reports not working. Running `flatpak update` updated `org.freedesktop.Platform.GL.nvidia-510-...` and fixed things. The `WEBKIT_DISABLE_...` trick also worked before I did the `flatpak update`.

Comment: This is still a thing unfortunately, performed a clean installation of 23.10, installed gnucash and reports are blank. Running with the WebKit command sorts the issue... Is there a more permanent fix available?

Comment: I can't remember if I installed gnucash with flatpak or not, but I'm experiencing the same problem (reports not showing up) on linux mint. I'm not on that computer right now but I'll test this when I can.

Comment: `WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1 flatpak run org.gnucash.GnuCash` Did not work for me. The reports still do not render in the application. But if I export the report to a PDF document, the report is viewable in the PDF. So I have a painful work around. I'm running Linux Mint.